# ¿Cuántos qmenu hay en un qmenubar?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

El escenario es una ventana principal construida a partir de `QMainWindows` con una barra de menú, esta ventana principal esta implementada por código generado con `QDessigner` y `Pyuic4.exe`, a la misma la referencio así:

```
from menu import Ui_MainWindow
```

Tal como se ve en el siguiente código:

```
<b></b>
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore  
from menu import Ui_MainWindow
from ctrlarticulos import FichaArticulos  
from ctrlclientes import FichaClientes  
from ctrlconfig import FichaConfig  
from ctrlmarcas import FichaMarcas  
from ctrlnotapedido import FichaNotaPedido  
from ctrlordencompra import FichaOrdenCompra  
from ctrlproveedores import FichaProveedores  
from ctrlremitocompra import FichaRemitoCompra  
from ctrlremitoventa import FichaRemitoVenta 
from ctrlrubros import FichaRubros  
from ctrlstockgeneral import FichaStockGeneral  
from ctrlusuarios import FichaUsuarios  
from ctrlventa import FichaVentas  
from ctrlvernotaspedido import FichaVerNotasPedido  
from ctrlverordenescompra import FichaVerOrdenCompra  
from ctrlverremitoscompra import FichaVerRemitosCompra  
from ctrlverremitosventa import FichaVerRemitosVenta  
from ctrlversaldostodosclientes import FichaVerSaldosTodosClientes  


class MainMenu(QtGui.QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ventana = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ventana.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.ventana.actionTerminar,
                 QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),
                 QtGui.qApp,
                 QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/inventory_maintenance_256.png')
        self.ventana.actionAr_culos.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionAr_culos.triggered.connect(self.carpetaarticulos)
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/Large_group.png')
        self.ventana.actionClientes.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionClientes.triggered.connect(self.carpetaclientes)
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/marcas.png')
        self.ventana.actionMarcas.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionMarcas.triggered.connect(self.carpetamarcas)                         self.ventana.actionNota_de_pedido.triggered.connect(self.registranotapedido)
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/notepad-icon-7.png')
        self.ventana.actionNota_de_pedido.setIcon(icono)
    self.ventana.actionNotas_de_pedido.triggered.connect(self.vernotaspedido)
        self.ventana.actionNotas_de_pedido.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionOrden_de_compra.setIcon(icono)
            self.ventana.actionOrden_de_compra.triggered.connect(self.registraordencompra)
        self.ventana.actionOrdenes_de_compra.setIcon(icono)
    self.ventana.actionOrdenes_de_compra.triggered.connect(self.verordencompra)

        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/Order tracking.ico')
        self.ventana.actionStock_general.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionStock_general.triggered.connect(self.verstockgeneral)

        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/inventory_maintenance_256.png')
        self.ventana.actionRemitos.triggered.connect(self.verremitosventa)
        self.ventana.actionRemitos.setIcon(icono)
       self.ventana.actionRemito.triggered.connect(self.registroremitoventa)
       self.ventana.actionRemito.setIcon(icono)
    self.ventana.actionRemito_de_compra.triggered.connect(self.registroremitocompra)
        self.ventana.actionRemito_de_compra.setIcon(icono)
    self.ventana.actionRemitos_de_compra.triggered.connect(self.verremitocompra)
        self.ventana.actionRemitos_de_compra.setIcon(icono)
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/users_group_people_friends-256.png')
    self.ventana.actionProveedores.triggered.connect(self.carpetaproveedores)
        self.ventana.actionProveedores.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionUsuarios.triggered.connect(self.carpetausuarios)
        self.ventana.actionUsuarios.setIcon(icono)
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/rubros.png')
        self.ventana.actionRubros.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionRubros.triggered.connect(self.carpetarubros)
        icono = QtGui.QIcon(':/advancedsettings.png')
        self.ventana.actionCinfiguraci_n.setIcon(icono)
        self.ventana.actionCinfiguraci_n.triggered.connect(self.carpetaconfig)
        self.ventana.actionTodos.triggered.connect(self.versaldostodosclientes)

    self.ventana.actionFactura_electr_nica.triggered.connect(self.registraventacae)

        self.fart = FichaArticulos()
        self.ccli = FichaClientes()
        self.cconf = FichaConfig()
        self.cmar = FichaMarcas()
        self.cnped = FichaNotaPedido()
        self.cocp = FichaOrdenCompra()
        self.cpro = FichaProveedores()
        self.crem = FichaRemitoVenta()
        self.cremc = FichaRemitoCompra()
        self.crub = FichaRubros()
        self.cstkg = FichaStockGeneral()
        self.cusu = FichaUsuarios()
        self.cvcae = FichaVentas()
        self.cvnp = FichaVerNotasPedido()
        self.cvoc = FichaVerOrdenCompra()
        self.cvremv = FichaVerRemitosVenta()
        self.cvremc = FichaVerRemitosCompra()
        self.cvstc = FichaVerSaldosTodosClientes()

    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fart.close()
        self.ccli.close()
        self.cconf.close()
        self.cmar.close()
        self.cnped.close()
        self.cocp.close()
        self.cpro.close()
        self.crem.close()
        self.cremc.close()
        self.crub.close()
        self.cstkg.close()
        self.cusu.close()
        self.cvcae.close()
        self.cvnp.close()
        self.cvoc.close()
        self.cvremv.close()
        self.close()
```

El aspecto de esto es mas o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es agregar un login a este programa, y como van a ser mas de dos operadores, se quiere que cada operador pueda acceder a distintos items del menú.

Para lograr esto se me ocurrio crear un función usuario en la clase `mainWindow` y llamarla desde la clase que realiza el `login`, despues al hacer el `show`, solo se presentarian los item de menu habilitados para ese usuario en particular.

Pondria el `enable` en `False` en todos los items de menu ya en el `QDessigner`, y al loguear al usuario levantar que menus especificos puede usar y pasarlos a `True`, pense en recorrer el `self.ventana.menubar` y ver qué objetos tiene agregados a fin de habilitarlos o no según los datos leídos de una tabla de datos, esto último es lo que no se como hacer.

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu codigo actual

Comment: Fer. Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Para darte una respuesta lo más acertada posible suele ser necesario que presentes un ejemplo mínimo de tu situación actual. Además, presentar código ayuda a demostrar que al menos has intentado resolverlo por tus propios medios y esto es algo que aquí se suele valorar.